# Figure out a set of json data in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, json

Can anyone help to find the json format of the code? I trying different combination of json format but still unable to work. Below shows the part of code that is use. I'm not sure what the format in notification.json. Hoping that someone able to figure that out.

```
     $.get('notification.json').then(data => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            notificationInterval = scheduleNotification(data, true);
        }, 1000);

        $(".notification-close-btn").click(function () {
            $(".notification-popup").stop().slideToggle('slow');
            clearInterval(notificationInterval);
            notificationInterval = scheduleNotification(data, false);
        });
    })

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        scaleContent();
    });

    scaleContent();
});



  function scheduleNotification(data, initData) {
    if (initData) {
        setNotificationData(data);
    }
    return setInterval(function () {
        setNotificationData(data);
    }, data.duration * 1000);
}

function setNotificationData(data) {
    if (!$(".notification-popup").is(':visible')) {
        data.index = data.index >= 0 ? data.index + 1 : 0;
        var index = data.index % data.content.length;
        $('.notification-text-1').text(data.content[index].text1);
        $('.notification-text-2').text(data.content[index].text2);
        $('.notification-text-3').text(data.content[index].text3);

        notificationProgressInterval = setInterval(function () {
            var width = +document.getElementById("notification-progress-bar").style.width.replace('%', '');
            if (width <= 0) {
                clearInterval(notificationProgressInterval);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.getElementById("notification-progress-bar").style.width = '100%';
                }, 100);
            } else {
                width = width - 0.1;
                document.getElementById("notification-progress-bar").style.width = width + "%";
            }
        }, data.duration);
    }
    $(".notification-popup").stop().slideToggle('slow');
}
```

Comment: Where is JSON ? All i see is jQuery code and function doing something.

Comment: The question is missing scheduleNotification code.

Comment: scheduleNotification code updated

Comment: the code require notification.json and i dont have that and i tried different of format but still dont work

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` after `.then` in your $.get `request` See whats coming there.

Comment: @N.Tec Then please also post what you tried and what error you got. Also, why not just rewrite it to use the data format that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please fix your code :

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
        scaleContent();
    });

    scaleContent();
});
```

I believe you meant as below:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
        scaleContent();
    });
```

and about your original question then notification.json should have below data then it will work:

```
{
    index: 2,
    duration: 2,
    content: [{text1: 'test'}, {text2:  'test1'}, {text3: 'test2'}]
}
```

Comment: what is the index and duration means?

Comment: Those are keys inside the json object required by various other methods in your code.